# python find second occurence of a set in a column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe:

```
ID        Status  
100         X  
100         Y  
100         Y  
100         Z  
100         A  
100         Y  
100         Y  
100         Y  
100         X  
100         X  
100         Y  
100         Y  
200         A  
200         B  
200         Y  
200         Y  
200         C  
200         Y  
200         Y   
200         Z
```

For every non-consecutive occurence of the element Y, I want the Status to change based on the number of times Y appears. My expected output is:

```
ID        Status  
100         X  
100         Y  
100         Y  
100         Z  
100         A  
100         Y1  
100         Y1  
100         Y1  
100         X  
100         X  
100         Y2  
100         Y2  
200         A  
200         B  
200         Y  
200         Y  
200         C  
200         Y1  
200         Y1   
200         Z
```

I've tried the following:

```
df['index'] = pd.np.where(df['Status']==Y, df.groupby(['ID']).cumcount(),0)
```

which indexes every occurence of Y. Then I count the difference like so:

```
df['diff'] = df['index'] - df['index'].shift(1)
```

Then I choose every point df['diff'] >1 becomes a new Status value, 'Y1'.

```
df['Status']=pd.np.where(df['diff']>1, 'Y1', df['Status'])
```

The above, however, identifies *every* point where Y occurs. I need to filter out the first time that Y occurs and solve for subsequent occurrences.  I am ok even with the following output:

```
ID        Status  
100         X  
100         Y  
100         Y  
100         Z  
100         A  
100         Y1  
100         Y1  
100         Y1  
100         X  
100         X  
100         Y1  
100         Y1  
200         A  
200         B  
200         Y  
200         Y  
200         C  
200         Y1  
200         Y1   
200         Z
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way via `groupby` + `transform`:

```
def enum(x):
    mask = x.eq('Y')
    y = mask & x.ne(x.shift())
    z = y.cumsum().sub(1).where(mask).fillna(0).astype(int).astype(str)
    return z.mask(z == '0', '')

df['Status'] += df.groupby('ID')['Status'].transform(enum)

print(df)

     ID Status
0   100      X
1   100      Y
2   100      Y
3   100      Z
4   100      A
5   100     Y1
6   100     Y1
7   100     Y1
8   100      X
9   100      X
10  100     Y2
11  100     Y2
12  200      A
13  200      B
14  200      Y
15  200      Y
16  200      C
17  200     Y1
18  200     Y1
19  200      Z
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what is happening here? When I try this, I get a Length mismatch error:  Expected axis has 729261 elements, new values have 729262 elements

Comment: I can't replicate your error. Roughly, we check if a value is `Y` and not the same as the value before. Take the cumulative sum, subtract 1 so we begin with 0, filter for only values which are `Y` (otherwise use null), fill nulls with 0, convert to integers and then strings. Finally remove the 0. Perform all the above by group.

Comment: This works, thanks! The error was due to an additional row in my dataframe that didn't have an ID attached. Dropping this row solved it.